# integral of this expression

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

What is the integral of this expression:

$$\int\operatorname{e}^{ts}dt$$ where t is the variable and s is the parameter. i want it in this general form and also maybe slight variations such as if $t$ now becomes $t^2$. but the exact problem I am facing is this: $$\frac{dQ}{dt} + \frac{rQ}{100} =  \frac{r}{4}$$Q is a function of time $t$. I want to solve this differential equation. Thanks for any help you can give me(I know it's a simple one but help will be much appreciated)

Comment: $\int e^{ts}dt = \frac{1}{s}e^{ts}+C$

Comment: $\frac1s e^{ts}+k$? I wouldn't call $t\mapsto t^2$ a slight variation though, that would change the integral completely - in fact this would make it impossible to write in terms of elementary functions

Comment: Integral of $\exp{st}$? A nice joke. :-)

Comment: You might prefer to solve something like $\int \frac{1}{25-Q}\, dQ = \int \frac{r}{100}\, dt$

Answer (score 0):

***Hint*** for the differential equation

I suppose that r is a constant
$$\frac{dQ}{dt} + \frac{rQ}{100} =  \frac{r}{4}$$
I used the integrating factor $\mu=e^{rt/100}$ but it's also separable 
$$Q'e^{rt/100} + e^{rt/100}\frac{rQ}{100} = e^{rt/100} \frac{r}{4}$$
$$(Qe^{rt/100})' = e^{rt/100} \frac{r}{4}$$
Integrate 
$$(Qe^{rt/100}) =  \frac{r}{4}\int e^{rt/100}dt $$
$$(Qe^{rt/100}) =  \frac{100r}{4r}e^{rt/100} +K\frac{r}{4}$$
$$(Qe^{rt/100}) =  25e^{rt/100} +K\frac{r}{4}$$
$$Q(t)=  \frac{r}{4}Ke^{-rt/100}+25$$
$$\boxed{Q(t)= Ce^{-rt/100}+25}$$

---

Edit

Note that 
$$\int e^{ax}dx= \frac {e^{ax}} a$$
$$ \implies \int e^{rt/100}dt=  {e^{rt/100}} \frac {100}{r}$$

Comment: i see a $K$ and then i see a $C$. dont get that part. and also $\int e^{rt/100} dt$ part. Maybe I am just lacking some fundamental understanding in integrations involving the exponential?

Comment: @Spirit_bird $C$ is just a new name for the arbitrary constant - $C=\frac{rK}4$. As for integrating an exponential, use the results given to you in the comment of the question, with $s=-r/100$

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: @Spirit_bird John give you the right explanationa bout the constant ...

Comment: yes he did thanks @Isham

Comment: @Spirit_bird I added a line for the integral thats a well known result you have to remember about integrating the exponential